# Trouble with Django Channels AllowedHostsOriginValidator

Tags: django, flutter, django-channels

Everytime I use the AllowedHostsoriginValidator I'm unable to get a websocket connection. it immediately handshakes, rejects and disconnects :
(where 'my ip' is my ip)

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/joingroup/8598969d-3dfa-4017-849c-dcbb71c1f9f0/ [my ip:62745]
WebSocket REJECT /ws/joingroup/8598969d-3dfa-4017-849c-dcbb71c1f9f0/ [my ip:62745]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/joingroup/8598969d-3dfa-4017-849c-dcbb71c1f9f0/ [my ip:62745]
```

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
         
          URLRouter(
            uppicdoapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
    ,
})
```

my settings.py file i have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '10.0.2.2', 'my ip']
```

now when I remove that allowedhostsoriginvalidator, I am able to connect!
Is there something I'm missing for the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting?

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add 'origin':'127.0.0.1(whatever domain you have in your allowed host)' in your header.

```
IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/'),
    headers: {
      "origin":"ws://127.0.0.1:8000"
    });
```

In Allowed Host: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ws://127.0.0.1:8000', 'ws://127.0.0.1',]`

But In production make sure you include your full URL in the allowed host (for example, .allowed-domain.com) or a full origin, in the format scheme://domain[:port] (for example, http://allowed-domain.com:80). Port is optional, but recommended

Comment: thanks for the response. im just seeing this now. have the same issue .

since im doing th is on flutter and sepcifically flutter WEB, it wont  allow me to use 
IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
because of :
Unsupported operation: Platform._version

when i use the websocket
WebSocketChannel.connect method. it doesnt allow to add headers.

So im stuck now on how to get passed this.

The only thign that works which isnt secure is by removign the AllowedHostsOriginValidator(